# The stack is executable, but should not?

Tags: security, stack, executable, shellcode

My issue is simple to explain !

A vulnerable program is able to execute a shellcode in the stack :

```
(with gdb)
   0xbffff6f3:  push   ...
=> 0xbffff6f8:  jns    ...
```

BUT, the stack is marked NOT executable :

```
(vmmap)
...
b7fff000-b8000000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 525141     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
bffdf000-c0000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

How can it be possible ?
I don't know where look. Have you any idea ?

Thank you.
Jc !

---

May be it can be useful :

```
jc@kali:~/init$ uname -a
Linux kali 3.18.0-kali1-586 #1 Debian 3.18.3-1~kali4 (2015-01-22) i686 GNU/Linux
jc@kali:~/init$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: i486-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.7.2-5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i486-linux-gnu --host=i486-linux-gnu --target=i486-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
```

Comment: Without seeing the program you're attacking and the shellcode you're using there's no way we can answer this question comprehensively, but I suspect the answer is probably that it's not executing code from the stack (which specifically requires a JMP to a stack address, it's not a general implication of any stack based attack).